# Parsing Json Array

Tags: java, json

I have been using the the Json library to try and parse the following Json data:

```
{"dailygameschedule": {
    "lastUpdatedOn": "2016-12-19 12:32:56 AM",
    "gameentry": [
        {
            "id": "37705",
            "date": "2016-04-03",
            "time": "1:30PM",
            "awayTeam": {
                ID: "133",
                City: "St. Louis",
                Name: "Cardinals"
                Abbreviation: "STL"
            },
            "homeTeam": {
                "ID": "132",
                "City": "Pittsburgh",
                "Name": "Pirates",
                "Abbreviation": "PIT"
            },
            "location": "PNC Park"
        },

        ...

    ]
}
```

I cant figure out how to get the `"gameentry"` array. I was looking at other threads for guidance but it is not quite working for me. Heres what I have so far:

```
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(todaysGames);
    String pageName = obj.getJSONObject("dailygameschedule").getString("lastUpdatedOn");



    System.out.println("2 asdfasdf "+ pageName);


    JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("gameentry");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        //String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("awayTeam.ID"));
    }
```

There error that im getting is:

> Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException:
>   JSONObject["gameentry"] not found.

Thanks!

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: But if it were valid JSON, you would have to get the object for key `"dailygamesschedule"`, and then get `"gameentry"` from that.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

```
JSONArray arr=obj.getJSONObject("dailygameschedule").getJSONArray("gameentry");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(i);
    String id = obj.getString("id");

    JSONObject awayTeam_obj=obj.getJSONObject("awayTeam");
    String awayTeam_ID = awayTeam_obj.getString("ID");
    String awayTeam_City = awayTeam_obj.getString("City");
    String awayTeam_Name = awayTeam_obj.getString("Name");

    JSONObject homeTeam_obj=obj.getJSONObject("homeTeam");
    String homeTeam_ID = homeTeam_obj.getString("ID");
    String homeTeam_City = homeTeam_obj.getString("City");
    String homeTeam_Name = homeTeam_obj.getString("Name");

}
```

Comment: this worked great. if was trying to access an element inside the "awayTeam"  , how would i do so?

Comment: @user2025187 can you help me to solve this issue?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44275601/display-the-list-of-events-within-the-calendar

Answer (score 0):

**gameentry** array is a member of **dailygameschedule** object, so you need to access it first.

```
 JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONObject("dailygameschedule").getJSONArray("gameentry");
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
    {
        //String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        System.out.println(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("awayTeam.ID"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not a valid JSON object, Just add '}' and gameentry not a root element you should get dailygamesschedule first and then get the gameentry